# Linker error using GCC, incl. for binutils and textinfo

Tags: c++, c, linux-mint, gcc4.7

I am getting this error every time, while compiling programs, configuring and installing some things like [binutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils), textinfo, etc.:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When will it come and what is the actual problem? Also, how do I solve it?

I removed binutils using the [Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)) package manager, but with the same result.

Comment: It seems you have a custom installation of the `binutils` package, and it was not properly configured.

Comment: actually, what ever i do the private installations i'll install them in seperate directories with --prefix=/private/.
But, this time luck came from back. LoL
Help me out yaar.. - @devnull

Comment: Re *"textinfo"*: Do you mean *[texinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo)* (without the second "t")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use gcc with the following option: `gcc --sysroot=/usr/local`

But, as the others told you in the comments, don't try to mess your system with critical packages such as the `binutils`, except if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

If you were attempting to install a version of binutils that should work alike the one found in `/usr/bin`, you should know that

- `gcc` invokes [ld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29#GNU_linker) with a `--sysroot=/` option.
- ld of binutils built from source with the default options rejects a `--sysroot` option.
- A `--sysroot` option will only be accepted by ld if binutils was configured with option `--with-sysroot`.

So, to cover this use case, configure binutils with option `--with-sysroot=/`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it should be the accepted one. For anyone compiling `binutils` from source, I recommend this resource: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/binutils.html